# sp_BlitzCache and cursors

Tags: cursors, sp-blitzcache

I'm running sp_BlitzCache (Brent Ozar) to get some information about database performance. The program that "attacks" this database uses cursors everywhere, so sp_BlitzCache gives me several lines where Query Text is something like 'FETCH API_CURSOR000000000045E513'. Is there any way to know what the select of that cursor is?
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, [Joe Sack writes](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/hunting-down-the-origins-of-fetch-api_cursor-and-sp_cursorfetch/) that you can track it down for live sessions with the help of sys.dm_exec_cursors, like this:

```
SELECT c.session_id, c.properties, c.creation_time, c.is_open, t.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (53) c
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (c.sql_handle) t
```

With 53 being a current live session holding a cursor open. You can also use 0 to get all current open sessions.

Granted, this is different than sp_BlitzCache - it's only for currently running queries.